# Chart js x-axis values getting repeated twice

Tags: javascript, momentjs, chart.js

I'm using the following code to generate a line chart using chart js plugin, in which I'm facing the problem where the x-axis values are repeated twice.

```
function newDate(days) {
    return moment().add(days, 'd').format('MM/DD');
}

var painChartContext = document.getElementById('pain_chart');
    var painChart = new Chart(painChartContext, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [newDate(-7), newDate(-6), newDate(-5), newDate(-4), newDate(-3), newDate(-2), newDate(-1)],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Pain",
                data: [8, 9, 7, 3, 10, 3, 4],
                fill: false,
                borderColor: '#b71705',
                spanGaps: true
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        displayFormats: {
                            'millisecond': 'MM/DD',
                            'second': 'MM/DD',
                            'minute': 'MM/DD',
                            'hour': 'MM/DD',
                            'day': 'MM/DD',
                            'week': 'MM/DD',
                            'month': 'MM/DD',
                            'quarter': 'MM/DD',
                            'year': 'MM/DD',
                        },
                        min: '04/13',
                        max: '04/19'
                    }                 
                }],
            },
        }
    });
```

As I mentioned above this gives me the following chart, where x-axis date values are repeating twice.[image]

Also in my console, I'm getting a warning message about moment js;

> Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.

which I think is because of this line of code;

```
function newDate(days) {
    return moment().add(days, 'd').format('MM/DD');
}
```

Kindly anyone give me a solution for this, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So chartjs is creating the x-axis labels dynamically and decided it can show two labels per day, which when formatted end up showing two dates that are the same.

Pass a new field `unit` to the `time` object and set it to `day`. this will cause the chart to only show one tick per day in the time frame. ([example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/80jodhpo/))

```
options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                     unit: 'day',
                }                 
            }],
        },
    }
```

Comment: This answer works, but what if my x-axis is not date, they are numbers? And i still want all repeated numbers to not show up?

Comment: @HarshPhoujdar did you figure that out, if so how?